# Find the equation of the plane that contains point A(3,0,1) and is parallel to vectors $\vec{u} = (1,2,0)$ and $\vec{v} = (0,3,1)$

Tags: proof-verification, vectors, analytic-geometry, cross-product, plane-geometry

> Find the equation of the plane that contains point A(3,0,1) and is
>   parallel to vectors $\vec{u} = (1,2,0)$ and $\vec{v} = (0,3,1)$

$\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = -\hat i -\hat j + 3 \hat k $.

Therefore we have plane $-x -y +3z = d$ and as A(3,0,1) belongs to this plane, $d = 0$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $\vec u\times\vec v=(2,-1,3)$.